# Copy approved items to another folder in different site using SharePoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Is it possible to copy approved items to another folder in the different library using workflow. The libraries are in different site.

can anyone please suggest

Comment: Is folder same for all approved items?

Comment: @VirajGorajia yes the folder will be the same for all approved items

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of box action to copy file to folder in document library.

you can use 3rd party action `Copy List Item Extended`.

http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Copy%20List%20Item%20Extended%20Activity

Comment: I use "Copy item in list to list" from actions but it dint work for me

Comment: Have you set full path of folder in action?

Comment: will it works in SharePoint 2013 i am using Approval Sharepoint 2010 template to workflow

Answer (score 0):

If it is a SharePoint On Premise Environment, you can create a custom Workflow activity for your SharePoint Designer.